# MySQL join table with itself with OR condition

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, mysql-5.1

I have a table FOLDERS, defining smth like directory structure. It contains the columns: ID, PARENT_ID and LINK_ID.

I cannot change the application which I have a problem now with a slow query.

This application has a logic that PARENT_ID could refer both to ID **or** LINK_ID.

Also, I cannot change the query, that I found slows down the whole our ETL process:

```
SELECT  folders.ID AS OrigFolderID, parentfolder.ID, parentfolder.Name 
FROM    folders 
          LEFT JOIN folders AS parentfolder ON folders.ParentID=parentfolder.ID OR folders.ParentID=parentfolder.LinkID
WHERE   folders.ID IN                (112450385,188823933,211307470,211403833,211545367,212449523,212539966)
```

We can change database however, removing or adding indexes.

Are there any chance to speed up this query?

It seems that the indexes on "parentfolder" are not working (there are indexes on LinkID, on ParentId, and on ID (which is a primary key), and the table is fully scanned. There are 200K rows in it.

Comment: Put an explain before the query edit your question with the results.Also show the table definitions

Comment: If you cannot change the query, you're pretty much out of options. You have all the indexes that _could have_ helped you if you could take out the `OR`s from the query. `OR`s pretty much eliminate index use in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `ID` and `LinkID` are each indexed.

`OR` is the killer.  You *must* find a way to change the query; no tuning, etc, can fix the performance problem.

`LEFT` is suspicious -- Do you want NULLs if there is no parent?

The `OR` can be turned into `UNION DISTINCT` of two selects -- one with either side of the `OR`.

Comment: Hi, Rick! Thanks you for the answer. I cannot change the query, so there is no way to fix the problem. We will try to use MS SQL Server for this application, or we will try to make the table smaller. Thanks!